# When if means iff and if, respectively?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

It seems sometimes 'if' really means 'if and only if' (abbreviated as iff), and sometimes 'if but not necessarily only if'.   Is there a better usage with 'if' than the regular/default way?  Should I be more careful when writing technical writings?

Comment: If you mean "only if" you can write "only if" if you just mean "if" then just write "if".  If you are writing mathematical proofs then write "iff" if that is your intent.

Comment: Yes, in causal use, "if" can mean either "*sufficient*", or "*necessary and sufficient*", and there's no way to know for sure. If you want to be completely unambiguous , and your audience is likely to be familiar with the word "iff", use that. Otherwise, you can use circumlocutions like I did above.

Comment: @Jim more precisely, "[...] then write "iff" iff that is your intent.", right? ;)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel- Precisely!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. To be clear and precise, use **if** *A* **then** *B* for an implication, that is, when every case where *A* is true *B* is also true, but not necessarily the converse.
2. The following are more or less standard interpretations of everyday English as logic statements, but **do not depend on people understanding them this way**:

   - *A* **if** *B* -- means *if B then A*, that is, whenever *B* is true *A* is also. (Note the reversed order.)
   - *A* **only if** *B* -- means *if A then B* (whenever *A* is true, so is *B*).
   - *A* **if and only if** *B* means *if A then B* **and** *if B then A*, that is, whenever *A* is true then so is *B*, and vice versa.
   - *A* **is equivalent to** *B* means the same as *A if and only if B*

In particular, do not depend on the first of these, *A if B*, meaning anything in particular.  People sometimes use it in everyday English to mean *if A then B*, *if B then A*, or even *A if and only if B*.

If you really want people to hear you carefully, then spell things out carefully. Do not hesitate to add *but not the reverse* or whatever, to dispel doubt or confusion.

As for *iff*: It is an abbreviation, and its use is pretty much confined to works of mathematics and logic. And it should be so confined. Do not expect an average English reader to note that you wrote *iff* or to understand that you meant something different from *if*.  *Iff* is sometimes used in programming texts, and it is just as often misunderstood there ;-). It is commonly misinterpreted outside of math and logic contexts as a typo for *if*.

Answer (score 3):

Iff the writing is super technical and focused on formal logic then you should use 'iff'. However, if the writing is casual or if it is not concerned about logical nuance then you should simply stick to regular 'if' to mean both.

In those few cases where the ambiguity between iff and if are of concern (e.g. 'If you want to fly a plane, you should get a pilot's license.') you can almost always reword just to replace the ambiguous 'if' with 'if and only if' (e.g. 'You should get a pilot's license only if you want to fly a plane.') As a general rule of thumb 'iff' should *only* be used in the context of texts heavily focused on logical axioms.

Answer (score 2):

In formal writing, even about mathematical logic, it is better to spell out "if and only if" rather than writing "iff".  In informal mathematical writing, on the other hand, "iff" is quite common.

In mathematics, "if" would ordinarily be understood as meaning a one-way implication (without asserting or denying the converse).  To assert the implications in both directions, use "if and only if".

There is, however, a traditional exception, allowing the use of "if" for a two-way implication in definitions.  Thus, it would be correct to write "we call a positive integer prime if it has exactly two positive integer divisors".  The "if" here really means "if and only if", but that would be understood because the context is a definition.